# how to select session array and database item to check

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, session

i have a session array ie.$_SESSION['cart_array'] and the array contains

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [item_id] => qwerty [quantity] => 1 [unit_price] => 500 ) [1] => Array ( [item_id] => skjbm [quantity] => 2 [unit_price] => 100 ) )
```

now i inserted this array into databse using my sql query..my query is

```
$insert_query = 'INSERT INTO product_added (id,order_id,email,item_id,unit_price,quantity,total,pay_status) values ';foreach($_SESSION['cart_array'] as $each_item){ 

$insert_query .= "('','$OrderId','','".$each_item['item_id']."','".$each_item['unit_price']."','".$each_item['quantity']."','".$each_item['unit_price']*$each_item['quantity']."',''),";}$query = rtrim($insert_query, ',');if(mysql_query($query)){echo 1;}else{
echo 0;}
```

my database entry record is

```
item_id unit_price quantity
qwerty      500       1
skjbm       100       2
```

till now its ok.....
now user update the quatity of existing item_id and the new array is

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [item_id] => qwerty [quantity] => 5 [unit_price] => 500 ) [1] => Array ( [item_id] => skjbm [quantity] => 6 [unit_price] => 100 ) )
```

how can i check the existing entry of data in database with current session and update the specific item_id's quantity if any chagnges happend in cart.thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before insert just judge the specific data is existing or not through item id. then the data is not existing in table and do insert , otherwise do update op. Following is my short code for your reference.

```
<?php

$cart_array = $_SESSION['cart_array'];;
$item_ids = array();
if ($cart_array) {
  foreach ($cart_array as $k => $v) {
    $item_ids[$v['item_id']] = 1;
   }
 }

//before insert do a check
$qry = sprintf("SELECT * FROM product_added WHERE id in (%s)",          implode(',', $item_ids));
$result = mysql_query($qry);
$existing_item_ids = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     $existing_item_ids[$row['item_id']] = 1;
}
$insrtion_arr = array();
$updated_arr = array();

if (!$existing_item_ids) { // if empty , the all cart data will insert into database
    $insrtion_arr = $item_ids;
  } else {
    foreach ($item_ids as $v) {
           if (isset($existing_item_ids[$v])) {
               $updated_arr[$v] = 1;
           } else {
              $insrtion_arr[$v] = 1;
         }
    }
  }
 //loop cart data and do database operation
 foreach ($cart_array as $k => $v) {
       if (isset($insrtion_arr[$v['item_id']])) {
            // do insert
        }   
       if (isset($updated_arr[$v['item_id']])) {
          // do update                                                                
        }   
    }
```

Hope this can help you!

Comment: thanks for valuable response but now it show the error-: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in line 46 and my line 46 is:if (isset($insrtion_arr[$v])) ,,,2nd error  Illegal offset type in isset or empty in line 50 and my line 50 is:if (isset($updated_arr[$v]))..please solve this

Comment: sorry there is a mistake that you said , i re-edit the code , pls try again. @priyabratasen

Comment: do suggest where i am wrong   my code is .....->$id = $_SESSION['cart_array'];$ta= count($id);for($i=0;$i < $ta;$i++){
$qry = ("SELECT * FROM product_added WHERE item_id='".$id[$i]['item_id']."'"); 
$result = mysql_query($qry);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $qty = $row['quantity']; // Original Quantity Number
    if ($qty !== $id[$i]['quantity']){
  $sql_update=("UPDATE product_added SET quantity='".$id[$i]['quantity']."' WHERE item_id='".$id[$i]['item_id']."' "); 
  echo "updated";
  
       
     };


}

Comment: what will be my mysql code to update only quantity of that item_id into database

Comment: what is my mistake above in for loop,,why it is not updated in database

Comment: did you copy the sql to mysql and execute ? what the error you got ?@priyabratasen

Comment: what is my mistake above in for loop,,why it is not updated in database

Comment: please pay a attention to my for loop in comment and told me why it is not working no error show but not update in database

Comment: please echo $sql_update and copy it into mysql console , what the result you got ? @priyabratasen

Comment: ya @cherry u made my day every thing goes fi9..thank you so much